# Unable to run training command for LaBSE

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to reproduce the fine-tuning stage of LaBSE[https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/projects/labse] model.

I have cloned the [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) repository. Set the enironment path as follows.

```py
%env PYTHONPATH='/env/python:/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/p3_sentence_similiarity/models'
!echo $PYTHONPATH
```

output: '/env/python:/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/p3_sentence_similiarity/models'

installed pre-requisites

```py
!pip install -U tensorflow
!pip install -U "tensorflow-text==2.10.*"
!pip install tf-models-official
```

Then I try to run the labse training command in readme.md.

```py
python3 /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/p3_sentence_similiarity/models/official/projects/labse/train.py \
  --experiment=labse/train \
  --config_file=/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/p3_sentence_similiarity/models/official/projects/labse/experiments/labse_bert_base.yaml \
  --config_file=/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/p3_sentence_similiarity/models/official/projects/labse/experiments/labse_base.yaml \
  --params_override=${PARAMS} \
  --model_dir=/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/p3_sentence_similiarity/models \
  --mode=train_and_eval
```

### Issue

I get the following error.

File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/p3_sentence_similiarity/models/official/projects/labse/train.py", line 23, in 
from official.projects.labse import config_labse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.projects.labse'

The import statement `python from official.projects.labse import config_labse`  fails

### System information

I executed this on colab as well as in  a GPU machine. However in both environments I get the same error.

```
 

I need to know why the import statement failed and what corrective action should be taken for this.
```